# Scrapy: Batch processing before spider closes down

Tags: scrapy

I use Scrapy to collect new contacts into my Hubspot account. Now I started to use the pipeline. However, that would lead to a lot of API calls, as each item is handled by itself. Since Hubspot also has an API call for batch processing, I wonder if there is a way to access all items at the end, once my crawler is done.
**pipelines.py**

```
class InsertDataToHubspot:
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(hubspot_api=crawler.settings.get("HUBSPOT_API"),)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # INSERT INTO HUBSPOT VIA API CALL
        return item
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement batching in your pipeline: have the pipeline store input items in a local variable, flush them every N items, and use `close_spider` to flush the last batch.